# Can't specify a Number Type when appending to a list attribute in DynamoDB

Tags: javascript, amazon-dynamodb

I am having trouble appending a value as a number to a list attribute in DynamoDB.  All the examples I can find are just that, "examples", rather than pragmatic code, so they use a constant as the value.  I am passing a variable, and getting bad results.

This code will add the value, but in Dynamo the outcome of running this 3X is:
[ { "S" : "1" }, { "S" : "2" }, { "S" : "3" } ]

But I want the data to be [ { "N" : "1" }, { "N" : "2" }, { "N" : "3" } ]

```
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const params = {
            TableName: tableName,
            Key: {
                'userId'    : userId,
                'stopGroup' : stopGroup
            },
            UpdateExpression: "SET #stopIds= list_append(if_not_exists(#stopIds, :emptyList), :stopVal)",
            ExpressionAttributeNames: {
                "#stopIds"  : "stopIds"
            },
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                ':emptyList'    : [],
                ':stopVal'      : [stopId]   //HERE IS THE VALUE TO BE APPENDED

            },
        };
        docClient.update(params, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Unable to insert =>", JSON.stringify(err))
                return reject("Unable to insert");
            }
            console.log("Saved Data, ", JSON.stringify(data));
            resolve(data);
        });
    });
```

I have tried the following:

```
':stopVal'      : {"NS":stopId}     =====> Result: Unable to insert => {"message":"Invalid UpdateExpression: Incorrect operand type for operator or function; operator or function: list_append, operand type: M"
':stopVal'      : [{"N": stopId}]   =====> Result: { "M" : { "N" : { "S" : "5" } } }
':stopVal'      : [{"NS": stopId}]  =====> Result: [ { "M" : { "N" : { "S" : "5" } } } ]
':stopVal'      : {"N":[stopId]}    =====> Result: Unable to insert => {"message":"Invalid UpdateExpression: Incorrect operand type for operator or function; operator or function: list_append, operand type: M" ...
':stopVal'      : {"NS":[stopId]}   =====> Result: (Same Err)
```

And even moving the type specifier up into the list_append() function:

```
UpdateExpression: "SET #stopIds= list_append(if_not_exists(#stopIds, :emptyList), {"NS": :stopVal})",
```

yields:

```
Syntax error in module 'index': SyntaxError
            UpdateExpression: "SET #stopIds= list_append(if_not_exists(#stopIds, :emptyList), {"NS": :stopVal})",
                                                                                                ^^
```

Clearly the answer has something to do with why it thinks I am specifying a Map, but I can't figure it out.

EDIT:  Note, this is a Lambda function, the stopId is passed from an Alexa Skill Slot, and it's of the type "AMAZON.NUMBER", accessed with slots.stopId.value

Comment: What is the javscript type of stopIds?

Comment: It's passed in via the Alexa skill; so only declared in the function prototype.  I assume that means it's passed as string/JSON and you use attributes to specify what it is.  Hence why it defaults to a string type.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ExpressionAttributeValues: {
  ':emptyList'    : [],
  ':stopVal'      : [parseInt(stopId)]   //HERE IS THE VALUE TO BE APPENDED
},
```

The DynamoDB SDK will set the type of values based on the javascript type (with some exceptions around sets).

If you want to explicitly set the type you need to use the regular DynamoDB API, not the DocumentClient. Then you would do something like

```
ExpressionAttributeValues: {
  ':emptyList'    : {"L": [] },
  ':stopVal'      : {"L": [ {"N":stopId}] }
},
```

Comment: Maybe I don't understand correctly... will this pass the type through from AWS Lambda to DynamoDB?  I will try it.

EDIT, From lambda: Error occured while saving stop group ReferenceError: int is not defined

Comment: Ah sorry about that, should be parseInt. Updated answer.